# DataSource connections pool

Tags: wso2

I have a data source configured with its connections pool ready to use, and it is exposed to my application via JDNI, but the code my colleagues wrote actually opens and closes a connection for every query. How does WSO2 handle this? Does it really close the connection given by the pool, or it ignores the close and just considers this connection free to be added back to the pool and ready to be used by any other client?

```
Connection conn = null;
CallableStatement cStmt = null;
try {
    Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    environment.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.jndi.CarbonJavaURLContextFactory");
    Context initContext = new InitialContext(environment);
    DataSource ds = (DataSource) initContext.lookup("jdbc/tvaccount");
    if (ds != null) {
        conn = ds.getConnection(); 
        cStmt = conn.prepareCall("{call getAccountStatusAttr(?)}");
        cStmt.setString("pUserLogin", userName);
        cStmt.execute();
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception while getting account status: ", e);
} finally {
    if (cStmt != null) {
        try {
                cStmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {             
        }
    }
    if (conn != null) {
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {               
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added this java code as a JAR file in WSO2 ESB and then accessed the method by using class mediator? if this is the case then it behaves like a normal java code wherein once the query is executed the connection will be closed.